# Fedora failing to recognize headphones

Tags: linux, audio, fedora

My headphones were working fine, but for some reason when I plug in the headphones into the USB port, I don't see them in the input or output tab in "Settings -> Hardware / Sound".

Comment: What version of Fedora are you using? Fedora 20? Is your headset + MIC combination use USB for sound output? Did you try this [link]?(https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/37448/fedora-20-first-install-audio-not-working/).

Comment: This is on Fedora 18. Checking the link

Comment: Did it work for you?